# What's our stance on questions about tips?

Tags: discussion

Should questions about tips be allowed? ie: Tips for falling asleep, tips for waking up, tips for eating fruit without getting sticky. I asked [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/438/how-to-quickly-fall-asleep) about how to fall asleep quickly, and it was put on hold as too broad. [This question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/289/how-to-wake-up-quickly) about how to wake up quickly is still open and only has one vote for it being too broad. So what should we do about questions like these? I feel that some of these questions aren't too broad because different life hacks work for different people. Isn't our goal to get most of our traffic from search engines? I think more answers will equal more traffic. Thoughts?

Comment: As the author of the second question: By now I think it is too broad myself and voted to close it. (I don't want to delete it before we get consensus here)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Too broad can be an issue. If you can ask for tips, without being too broad, that's great, go for it. I think many of these questions will bring down the site quality by attracting load after load of poor answers.

Ask questions that don't have an infinite amount of answers, or you'll run into that trouble. Something on which everyone has a different opinion will have this trouble also. Avoid asking those. When you ask a question, put it in a way that it is clearly understood, yet encourages a detailed, specific answer.

Yes, more answers can mean more traffic, but we don't want to sacrifice any site quality by attracting traffic, so asking questions that attract multitudes of answers is not beneficial to the site in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

According to [this answer](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1136/78) and the [way I define a lifehack](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1159/78), the questions you brought up are off topic because they are about psychological issues.

"Tips" in a general sense can be anything. We close/vote on questions based on the actual *subject matter* of the question, not whether or not it's a "tip" because ultimately most answers and comments are tips.

As for "Isn't our goal to get most of our traffic from search engines?" - **No**. Our goal is to provide meaningful content and help people with real issues. Questions like the ones you linked might be helpful to users, but they're not on topic for this site.