# Why isn't this question about opening ketchup packets on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions

[How can I keep from squirting myself with ketchup whenever I use ketchup packets?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/363/168)

Per [this meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/59/168), I think it fits the criteria.

- It is a problem most people encounter at some period in their life.
- It has a common solution (ripping it open with my fingers) that I want to improve. I have described what I've tried and why my current solution is not satisfactory to me.

The question has been closed (and I have since made an edit). Note that my goal is not getting it reopened. My goal is to have us be able to concretely explain why it was closed, assuming it should be. Right now, that reason seems to amount to "isn't lifehacky enough", which doesn't seem like something particularly quantifiable to me.

If the reason is has [too obvious a solution](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/43/168) of "use scissors or don't squeeze so hard", that's a pretty slippery slope in here that I don't think will serve us well. Take, for instance:

**Question**: [Lifehacks for waking up](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/239/what-are-some-waking-up-hacks-for-non-morning-person)

**Obvious Answer**: Use an alarm clock.

**Question**: [How do I remove ice from a windshield?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/286/remove-ice-from-windshield)

**Obvious answer**: Warm up the car and start scraping with an ice scraper. You'll get there eventually.

**Question**: [How do I keep pencils from breaking](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/213/168)

**Obvious answer**: Don't press so hard

**Question**: [How do I open clamshell packaging?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/22/168)

**Obvious answer**: Use stronger scissors or a box cutter.

**Question**: [How do I fill a container that won't fit in the sink?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/60/168)

**Obvious answer**: Make use of a smaller container.

Note that I'm not trying to point and say "Hey, these other ones are open, mine should be too." Maybe some of those should be closed as well. What I'm trying to do is get some sort of definition on what makes some of these okay but others not. On the surface, they all look pretty similar to me.

Comment: Try reading through the other meta posts, you may get a better idea of what is becoming acceptable

Comment: I've tried. You'll probably even noticed *I linked some of them*. We're pretty far from consensus.

Comment: I feel the "waking up" questions (mine too) should be closed, but I could not yet wrap my head around why. But yeah, I think some of them need closing.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I voted for them being too broad personally. They wouldn't even be able to get canonical answers if that was the goal.

Comment: It must on-topic anyhow. It is on-topic.