# Should questions dealing with how to speed up a process be on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

There are several examples thus far dealing with how to speed up a process. They provide a solution in the question itself but are asking about how to *quicken* this solution. They include

- https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1593/whats-the-fastest-way-to-ferment-juice
- [How can I dry my hair more quickly?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/1740/78)
- [Fastest way to boil water?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/178/fastest-way-to-boil-water)

To me, these questions seem to be off topic because they're not looking to solve a problem, they're looking to quicken *the process* that solves the problem.

What do you think? Should these types of questions be on topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes

Providing the asker includes *exactly* what they are doing now, and otherwise fits into [our new scope](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217/15).

I would consider "a better mousetrap" <sup>[[1]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_a_better_mousetrap,_and_the_world_will_beat_a_path_to_your_door)</sup> to be "looking for an alternative to a product or solution that they have tried" <sup>[[2]](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1217/15)</sup>.

Comment: I agree with this. The reason what they have tried is unsatisfactory to them is that it is to slow.