# Can we stop this close war?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

[Open a suitcase with a numeric lock when you forgot the key code](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/343/open-a-suitcase-with-a-numeric-lock-when-you-forgot-the-key-code)

---

This question has been closed, reopened, and closed again. Currently, it is in nomination for re-opening.

I think we should just ***stop closing/opening this question***. It is on-topic.

First off, why does legality really matter? If it was a person just trying to get their stuff after forgetting their passcode, it's perfectly legal. If it were a thief, not so much. But, how do we know?

Even if the person is a thief, we are not participating in crime. We are simply relaying experience that we've had. There is no crime in teaching or learning. Secondly, how do we verify that the person is a criminal? Have a background check run on every profile? Thirdly, it is not our job to be police. The police have that job.

If a question is obviously illegal ("How do I break a lock to a Blockbuster quickly and efficiently"), then I can understand. But if there's no pure proof that it's illegal, there's no reason to close it.

Comment: Also look at http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1165/lets-eat-some-cake in which @Matt-s explains what is happening here...

Comment: Oh, and for the record, I initiated this second reopening, since the question is on-topic.

Comment: @RichardBernards I agree. It is on-topic.

Comment: Its on topic, but too broad. http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/1167/129

Comment: @AngeloFuchs modified the question with an image to make it far more specific

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The question is on-topic. Leave it open.

If necessary, comment under the post with a simple explanation and link(s) to the appropriate meta post regarding its scope (this one included).

And your point that it is not our job to be police is valid, we shouldn't vote to close a question because it's possible to use the answers gained in an illegal fashion. That's stupid. We could probably find reasons to close all the questions, if that's the case.

Comment: I agree, there is a similar policy on metaSE related to questions that are typically about hacking / keyloggers, etc. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3528/dealing-with-questions-of-nefarious-intent  and the answer was if the question is on-topic, leave it open. If you have concerns, flag it for a moderator and explain your concerns.

Answer (score 2):

In a general way I say no don't close the open close war, we are in private beta right now. This is when we are supposed to be hashing out issues between beta users. How can we come to consensus if we decide not to vote for open or close on certain questions, thus closing the conversation we are supposed to be having at this point.