# Can we have a flag reason + queue for "This isn't a hack"?

Tags: discussion, flagging, review-queues

#### Can we have a new flag reason and review queue for "This isn't a hack"?

Inspired, somewhat, by [this question](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1124/15), answers can be given that are `0.00%` hackish. I think we can all agree that these don't help the community.

I propose that there is a new flag reason...

> #### it is not a hack
>
> This answer does not contain a lifehack. It is therefore off-topic, and may have to be removed.

...along with a new queue:

> ### Non-hack answers
>
> Which has the options:
>
> - Recommend deletion (`0.00%` lifehack)
> - Looks OK
> - Looks OK + Upvote

If the answer is deleted via sufficient <kbd>Recommend Deletion</kbd> votes, the question should be added to the "Low Quality Posts" queue, with a notation that

> N non-lifehack answers have been deleted from this question. Please especially consider if the question is on-topic.

Comment: While this may be useful in the future (it may fit under `Not an answer` reason), right now when the scope of Lifehacks isn't decided it would be difficult to vote on

Comment: @ZachSaucier I think the term "lifehack" will be forever ambiguous. What one person considers a "hack", another may consider "common sense".

Comment: I disagree. I think [this answer](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/101/78) says it well: a lifehack is an unconventional solution

Comment: @ZachSaucier conventional is cultural. What one would consider unconventional (or a solution) can be considered normal, common-sense or trivial by another. The term is ambiguous. I agree with Mooseman that this will stay that way.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs I address that in [this meta post](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1118/whats-our-target-culture/1129#1129) of mine. As for how to handle multiple cultures' "normals", we'll [need to wait for an example case](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/96/what-isnt-a-lifehack/101#comment1229_101)

Comment: @ZachSaucier I gave an example in that very thread (the orange peeler).

Comment: If you're asking for specific features to help moderate your site the second day in, that's a pretty decent sign you're going well outside the SE defined framework.  And that you should work to pull it back in, not stretch the framework.

Comment: *I think we can all agree that these don't help the community.* I think the community is pretty far from agreement on that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SE usually gives custom close reasons for questions, but rarely (if ever) custom flag reasons for answers.

I'm going to give the same advice i did on [Mi Yodeya Meta](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2210/5151):

> If an answer honestly tries to answer the question, then it looks OK. It might be a bad answer, worthy of being downvoted, but that's for outside the VLQ queue.

(VLQ means deleting, here.)