# How do we phrase the clause about illegal activities?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

Recently, we got a question asking about [How to dispose of dead body quickly?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1831/how-to-dispose-of-dead-body-quickly)<sup>1</sup>

> I am on the run from the police in my home town of Springhurst, and I need to get rid of the bodies. I only have one, and I won't kill anyone else later on so it doesn't need to be a repeatable method. I don't want to burry it - someone I knew did that and they went to prison.

Now this is of course off topic as it is against the SE terms of use.

However, this site, being quite different from others, will need a clause in the asking section *and* the answering section.

With that in mind, what are some suggestions on how to word this for both of the question and answer sections?

Comment: [Relevant](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8492/should-an-answer-that-encourages-illegal-activity-be-marked-as-offensive)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> How do we phrase the clause about illegal activities?

At the moment I'd say, ***you don't.*** Is this really a problem worth enumerating a rule/clause for?

I can appreciate the enthusiasm for working up a "policy" for anything that can ever possibly go wrong on this site, but be careful. You got one crazy, off-beat question (that probably wasn't even asked in good faith) and you're writing up four paragraphs to cover it.

Comment, close it, and move on. It was well handled. There's no need to "lawyer up" and get too overbearing around every random situation that happens on this site. You're just drawing an uneasy crowd; there's nothing to see here.

> [If you find yourself constantly adding](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1187/saving-lifehacks-can-we-make-this-a-topic-space-instead-of-a-vague-buzzword) warnings, exclusions, exceptions, caveats, faqs, subsections, twists & turns, and asterisks every time an issue comes up… this site will not work.

Answer (score -2):

*Please edit this (it's CW) to improve it.*

The Asking Clause:

> Questions asking for hacks that help with criminal activities, or imply that the solution will be used for criminal activities, are off topic here. We do not provide answers to these, and questions will be removed. From [here](http://stackexchange.com/legal/content-policy):
>
> > We will do our best to work with you and ensure a fair outcome in all cases. We reserve the right to **immediately suspend, without notice**, any content, account, or IP address which we determine to be submitting spam or other potentially damaging or disruptive content to the Network.
> >
> > **Hate Content, Defamation, and Libel**. Hate speech and other **objectionable content that is unlawful**, defamatory, and fraudulent. Note that an allegation of defamatory expression, in and of itself, does not establish defamation. The truth or falsehood of a bit of expression is a key element in establishing defamation, and we are not in a position to make that sort of fact-based judgment. That said, if we have reason to believe that a particular statement is defamatory (a court order, for example), we will remove that statement.

The Answering Clause:

> Answers proving hacks that help with criminal activities, or give a that solution that is likely be used for criminal activities will not be tolerated here. **Under any circumstances, Do not answer** with these details, or answer questions that request hacks for illegal activities.