# Canonical Questions and Answers

Tags: discussion

Recently this questions has been opened to try to eliminate the different "getting sticky while eating" questions: [How can I neatly eat messy food without "common" utensils?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1827/how-can-i-stop-my-fingers-getting-sticky-when-eating)

Is this the proper way to handle these types of issues (multiple similar questions)?

What should become of the questions that are now deemed duplicates? Should I delete my original question? [How to eat barbecue ribs without getting covered in barbecue sauce?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/47/how-to-eat-barbecue-ribs-without-getting-covered-in-barbecue-sauce)

Sorry if this is already laid out somewhere, I am just unfamiliar with this canonical question/answer format and want to understand what is expected.

Comment: Even if it is deemed proper usage of a canonical, there is no reason for you to delete your original question. People searching for a similar answer in the future would find your question and be pointed to the canonical, which is what we're wanting to happen.

Comment: @ZachSaucier Ok, makes sense. I haven't seen anything like this before so just trying to get a feel for how the community wants to handle this type of issue.

Answer (score 2):

**In my opinion there was no better way of handling this. Creating a catch all question stops the similar question chain.**

- That is not to say a "get sticky while eating" question that is actually unique won't come.

Your question was marked duplicate that doesn't mean that it was a bad question, just that the other question was better in a way. That way being that the newer question was made so that the "getting sticky while eating" question chain would just die out. Leaving your question up would probably be a good idea, because I am sure it is not up for deletion, and it may add quality to the site.

Your Question may Give a specific problem, while the other question was mostly to stop the perpetuation of this question chain, because it was going nowhere.

This is a Beta that means things are being tried out and implemented. The best way to stop your questions from being closed is to know [the scope](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/the-scope-of-lifehacks) and what is considered [off-topic.](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1124/how-do-we-define-what-is-on-topic-without-requiring-the-questioner-to-know-the-a?cb=1) Also, be active in the discussions for better rule creation.

And this wasn't really avoidable, people would have kept making similar questions, and can you really close a how-to for a orange as a how to for a apple.

**Should we do this for other similar questions:**

I would say yes, my reasoning:

- What else would we do? If left they are redundant and add questions to the site that are not quality.
- They set a bad standard. Basically they tell people that they can write what ever bad questions they fancy, without particularly caring what the content.

Maybe users can try to see if their question will branch a similar chain, but I really wouldn't see if this that possible.

Comment: I understand what we did here, just wondering if we should continue to do this for similar questions.