# What's so wrong about my comments?

Tags: discussion

There's been two questions where I comment a solution yet not a life-hack and mods have deleted them, I know comments aren't meant for solutions, but answers are meant for life-hack solutions. And that is why I posted my solutions as comments, cause they're not life-hacks. I'm sure that if posted those comments as answers they'd be DV because either they're not a life-hack or they'd be low quality. Since there's nothing else to elaborate besides making a simple comment, that's what I do, comment. I'm just providing what I think it might help, not an actual life-hack.

- I'm not spamming
- I'm not being sarcastic
- I'm not being offensive
- I'm not being disrespectful

So what's so wrong about those comments? If OP decides that's they're answer then so be it I'll post it as an answer. The point of this forum is the solution of everyday problems through out-of-the-box solutions. Things like "go buy an eraser-mate" or "Close your eyes while peeing" are definitely not out-of-the-box

[Question 1](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10329/how-do-i-clear-my-urination-chi-when-some-dude-is-at-the-urinal-next-to-me#comment14752_10329)

[Question 2](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/10309/alternative-to-white-out#comment14698_10309)

Comment: My favorite thing about the stackexchange sites is helping other people.  I rarely ask questions for myself.  The lifehacks site is frustrating for me for the reasons stated above by @JustDoIt.  Maybe we could agree to allow non-lifehack answers unless the questioner has already said that they are not acceptable.  For example, instead of asking "How can I remove pencil marks from paper?", they could ask "How can I remove pencil marks from paper without using an erasor?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments in your posts indicate your comments were deleted for being answers not comments.

Standard solutions are perfectly acceptable on Lifehacks, so feel free to post any standard solutions you have. Anyone who tells you conventional answers aren't allowed is just wrong. [Relevant meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/should-we-be-downvoting-conventional-answers).