# Should questions asking for alternatives to products be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

As long as the question is not asking for a product recommendation that is.

[I forgot my toothpaste and it is impossible to buy in this situation, are there any substitutes?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1714/i-forgot-my-toothpaste-and-it-is-impossible-to-buy-in-that-situation-are-there)

[Is there any way to kill a fly without a flyswatter?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1798/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-fly-without-a-flyswatter)

The idea is that they're looking for the same result they would get by using a product, just without a product. It seems to me like that would count as asking for a lifehack, or should they be off-topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, they should be on topic

The mentioned situation fits the definition of a lifehack:

> A lifehack is a technique that can be implemented quickly and is used to make one's physical life more efficient **when a more standard approach** (as defined by that area's experts) **or a product is either unavailable or undesirable**. Lifehacks are creative, meaning they use materials that are on hand for uses besides their intended use. - [Our lifehack defintion](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1159/78)