# Who should be our Moderators Pro Tempore be?

Tags: discussion, moderation

This community needs to start contributing some names they would like to act as provisional Moderators. Please read this: **[Moderators Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/)**.

Here are some basic guidelines:

- Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user’s profile (parent and meta) so we can see their activity ([see this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/150/elect-our-provisional-moderators) for reference).
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by editing the answer (not commenting), adding that they accept the nomination. Optionally they can write something about themselves. Use the `---` to separate it from the nomination.
- Self nominations are okay, and even encouraged. Most sites have not had sufficient time for many users to stand out. Self nomination is simply a way to say, “I’m interested. Let my record speak for itself.” Links to other activities may be helpful: Area 51 participation, participation in other sites, blog posts / social network referrals about the site, etc.

Here is what we are looking for in a Moderator...

We are seeing out members who are deeply engaged in the community’s development; members who:

- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Show an interest in their meta’s community-building activities.
- Lead by example, showing patience and respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Exhibit those intangible traits discussed in A Theory of Moderation.

Bonus points for:

- Members with participation in both meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).
- Area 51 participation, social network referrals, or blogging about the site.
- Members who have already shown an interest or ability to promote their community.

Please try to use a format similar to the following when posting a nomination under this question:

> ## [Name](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/25/j-musser)
>
> <sup>(liked to profile)</sup>
>
> ### [Meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/25/j-musser)
>
> <sup>(linked to meta profile)</sup>
>
> <sup>Details about the nominee</sup>
>
> They are active on both the main and meta sites. They were involved in the Scope creation and took lead in closing the Off Topic questions.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>Edited in by nominee</sup>
>
> I accept / decline this nomination
>
> I am Name / Age / Fun Fact <sup>1</sup> and I live in Location, so will be active on the site from Xpm - Ypm HTZ<sup>2</sup> (X<sub>1</sub>pm - Y<sub>1</sub>am UTC).
>
> <sup>1 Optional
>
>   2 Home Time Zone</sup>

Comment: @Sterno "If your meta site does not have a post to nominate Moderators, start one now! Pro Tem appointments will begin about two weeks after the site is created. The more guidance we receive, the more informed our choice." from the [blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).

Comment: @Sterno quite possibly... It may not be though, so I thought I'd start it.

Comment: @Sterno we seem to have graduated!

Comment: How many Moderator Pro Tems will there be?

Comment: @michaelpri usually 3

Comment: @J.Musser Will it just be the 3 people with the most upvotes on their nomination?

Comment: @michaelpri The community team looks over all of them. It's not solely based on upvotes, but more on the merits of the users themselves.

Comment: @Tim We haven't graduated yet. We're still in public beta.

Comment: @Shokhet I meant to public beta :0

Comment: Interesting, when they are finally going to announce the mods...

Comment: @Robert Any info when mods are going to be announced?

Comment: @nicael It may be another week or two. We're working internally on how best to resolve some problems so the new mods are working on roughly the same page (with each other and the community) when it comes to moderation... instead of the roughshod self-moderation we have now. See [You're touching on a problem I'm trying to resolve now — that when a question does not belong (arguably), the reasons to disallow it are so far off the mark, that when they get applied all over the site (inappropriaty) the entire site seems to take these big left turns into craziness.](http://bit.ly/14PHxN5)

Comment: @Rob Any info? A week, two weeks passed... Three, four weeks passed...

Comment: @Rob Five weeks passed. Even newer betas have their mods now.

Comment: To be fair, the pickings are pretty darn slim. The 2nd highest voted candidate who hasn't declined is at 4 votes. Most of the people who have taken to hashing out issues on meta either don't want the job, or have opinions that have been poorly received by the rest of the community. This site does not appear to have the necessary leadership to get off the ground and throwing a few diamonds on people's names isn't going to change that.

Comment: @Sterno yeah, that is a problem... There seems to be a lack of interest. I'll keep my eye out. If I notice anyone I could discuss some things with 'em, in case they're interested.

Comment: @nicael ...how were you able to [tag:featured] this?

Comment: @Shok Just added the tag with a life hack :D Btw, [read from there](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3080103#3080103)

Comment: @nicael I see :) ....I'm going to have to start doing that myself :)

Comment: @nicael, umm is that the standard thing done?

Comment: Yes, of course. There is not enough meta in you :D Btw, [try out the new feature by closing your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes) :)

Comment: Missed the opportunity :p I was gonna wait for your reply then, but then internet issues :/ I do like that feature - congrats on that high voted answer btw :p

Answer (score 26):

## [J. Musser](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/25/j-musser)

#### [Meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/25/j-musser)

[image: profile for J. Musser on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

He is active on both the main [<sup>(1)</sup>](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation) and meta [<sup>(2)</sup>](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation) sites. He was involved in the scope creation and took lead in closing the Off Topic questions.

---

## I respectfully accept.

I'm a lawn care/landscaping guy from Lancaster, Pennsylvania. I started on Stack Exchange because of [Gardening & Landscaping](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/) ([my account](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/users/419/j-musser)), a small new beta site at the time. That's where I learned about SE, starting 3 years, 5 months ago.

I have no prior experience with moderating Stack Exchange communities, beyond guiding communities using the tools SE provides when a regular user earns reputation in that community. However, I would enjoy the honor of helping to guide this community, and helping the site grow and bloom.

I enjoy both the topic of this site, and working 'behind the scenes' in meta.

Because I do outdoor work, I am often unavailable at the computer for short periods, but I will be on intermittently from 5:30 am or so, until 12:00 pm My time (9:30 am - 4:00 am UTC), 7 days a week. Different days will vary widely. I will be on the site's chat room whenever I'm on the site (well, also when I'm not around, so don't assume I'm in there just 'cause you can see my dp :D).

Fun fact: I'm the only user on Stack Overflow (really) to have [earned the marshal badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal?userid=1355089) without posting anything/having any rep changes (I'm still at 101 rep).

Comment: J. has an extraordinary depth of compassion, patience and dedication. In chat rooms, he spends extensive amounts of time educating and encouraging. SE can overwhelm new users, as it did me. J. is one of the main reasons I'm still here, continuing to learn, and looking forward to helping others. He embodies all the characteristics of a great moderator and applies them with grace. LH would be blessed to have him on its leadership team.

Answer (score 22):

## [Shokhet](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/59/shokhet)

#### [Meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/59/shokhet)

[image: profile for Shockhet on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

He is [active on meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users), and has a good amount of rep on the main site, showing knowledge on the site topic, and an interest in supporting this site through participating in meta, as well as chat discussions.

He was influential in our scope-building process, and has been very supportive, actively upholding the scope on the main site through comments and close votes, combined with the positive example of posting high-quality questions and answers there.

From all of my discussions, and working with Shokhet, he seems to be a friendly, honest community member.

<s>**I accept**</s>

Thank you for the nomination. I would love to see this site get off the ground, maybe even graduate at some point. I think the community can do this if we keep it together, and work to keep all questions in scope, and all answers push hard for high-quality answers.

**I'm sorry, but I'll have to sit this one out**

Recent changes in my schedule dictate that I won't be able to participate in LH as much as I used to (some of you may have noticed that I haven't so much as logged in the last two days), and it wouldn't be responsible to claim that I would be able to moderate here, if I don't have enough time to participate.
I hope I'll still pop in from time to time with a question or answer, but at the moment, it doesn't look like that will be on any kind of regular basis.

Comment: In my personal dealings with Shokhet in chat rooms, he is kind, patient, encouraging, quick to respond. He's dedicated to maintaining the quality of all aspects of Lifehacks, as evidenced by his participation in both beta and meta. He approaches even difficult discussions with humility and an open mind. I believe he's a person of integrity, who respects the SE system and the community it serves. He would moderate with a gentle yet firm hand, which is just what Lifehacks needs!

Answer (score 21):

## [ZachSaucier](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/78/zach-saucier)

### [Meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/78/zach-saucier)

[image: profile for Zach Saucier on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

 
I have the second most questions/answers on meta (currently first in [participation](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users)), have the highest number of useful answers on meta so far, have rep on several different SE sites, review on Lifehacks (as well as SO and GD.SE) daily, and stay active in our chatroom. I was part of the scope creation and attempt to enforce the scope that is set at the time, willing to change my outlook on issues if the community deems it appropriate to do so.

I'm in college and work as a web developer, thus I'm active on some part of SE throughout most of every day other than between 7-12am UTC or so.

I also can provide you with as many cat gifs as you'd like upon request :)

---

Due to multiple reasons, the primary being school starting again, I've lost interest and thus **revoke my nomination**.

Comment: And I can't get downvotes there...

Comment: Zach helped the site make it to public Beta, trying hard to improve the qualities of the content, and adding the rules. +1

Comment: +1 for cat gifs

Comment: I downvoted because we have disagreed on a few things - nothing personal to him.

Comment: @Tim I'm perfectly okay with that, just know that moderators act based on how the community rules when it comes to scope issues :)

Comment: I fully support this candidate as a moderator; he had been very helpful and active on the failed Web Design site and has done volumes of work in helping to improve both Web Design and Lifehacks in meta and chat.

Comment: @Zach yeah that's fine - I will accept the way the site works when it is set in stone :)

Answer (score 13):

## [Matt S.](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/8/matt-s)

### [Meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/8/matt-s)

[image: profile for Matt S. on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

 
He has the most questions/answers on meta, has rep on several different SE sites, reviews, and handles himself well. He was the actual writer of the scope creation and discusses scope, etc. in the site's chatroom.

---

Unfortunately Matt has declined the nomination:

> **I decline** - [MattS.](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/moderator-pro-tempore#comment1813_1274)

Comment: Not trying to be mean, but none of his answers are accepted...

Comment: @Tim "Accepted" answers mean next to nothing. Several of his answers are the top rated ones on the question

Comment: He put a lot of work into organizing Meta and trying to get focus on important issues.

Comment: Ah, you meant on main :P

Comment: I can't seem to edit the post right now, but I decline.

Answer (score 11):

## [Mooseman](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/15/mooseman)

#### [Meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/15/mooseman)

[image: profile for Mooseman at Lifehacks Stack Exchange, Q&A for people looking to bypass life's everyday problems with simple tricks]


[image: profile for Mooseman on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

He is one of the most active beta users and has the most reputation (First to reach 5,000). He is also active on meta, and has contributed to deciding what questions are on or off topic. He also helped make our tags better, both by answering or asking on meta and by creating/editing tags on beta. The first user to be awarded the [Strunk & White](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white), [Synonymizer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/badges/72/synonymizer), and [Research Assistant](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/help/badges/79/research-assistant) badges.

---

### I am happy to accept

I'm a programmer in the US who particularly enjoys helping people with creative solutions. As seen on [my activity tab](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/15/mooseman?tab=activity), I'm active at various times day and night. (I'm in EST: UTC-5)

Comment: @michaelpri That's according to rep and not up to date :)

Answer (score 6):

## [Sterno](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/168/sterno)

### [Meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/168/sterno)

[image: profile for Sterno on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

Sterno has provided useful comments and insightful answers to several questions on meta. He seems to understand our scope well and know what the heck he's talking about. He has a good bit of experience on other SE sites and carries himself well.

---

Unfortunately, Sterno declined:

> I've spent a few days thinking about it and I'm going to decline. I think any help I can give to this site I can do through Meta whether or not I'm a mod. My interest in the site is mostly from the "can it work, and if so how?" standpoint and not the actual subject matter. In particular, in its current form, I do not believe in this site enough to actually promote it to people, which is probably a good sign I shouldn't be a mod. - [Sterno](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/moderator-pro-tempore/1290?noredirect=1#comment1819_1290)

Comment: +1 From my experience with Sterno over at Arqade I can confirm he'd make an excellent moderator. He's patient and expresses his thoughts well. He's always willing to listen to the input of other users, even if he strongly disagrees with their views. On Lifehacks he's also been very active, and seems to have  very good idea of the problems the site faces and will need to overcome to be successful. I think having mods who aware of the challenges the site faces is extremely important in ensuring the site succeeds.

Comment: [One of Sterno's answers here on meta](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1170/is-no-an-answer/1184#1184), very few people have thought things through, or written as good answers as this.

Comment: I've spent a few days thinking about it and I'm going to decline. I think any help I can give to this site I can do through Meta whether or not I'm a mod. My interest in the site is mostly from the "can it work, and if so how?" standpoint and not the actual subject matter. In particular, in its current form, I do not believe in this site enough to actually promote it to people, which is probably a good sign I shouldn't be a mod.

Answer (score 4):

## [Gilles](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/1214/gilles)

### [Meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1214/gilles)

[image: profile for Gilles on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

I'll admit that I don't know Gilles all that well from around the network, as we don't share too many sites of common interest; however, from what I do know of him from our conversations in the [Junk Drawer](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19330/the-junk-drawer) on scope, he's educated and polite. His reputation among users on the network who I respect (besides for the large amount of "fake internet points" he's accrued) is certainly very impressive.

Here's what he wrote about himself on his [user profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/164368/Gilles):

> Moderator♦ *pro tempore* on French Language, Computer Science and
> Software Recommendations. I'm also a unix amateur, and a developer on
> embedded systems with a computer science background and security
> leanings by trade.

I'm not very active on those sites, but Gilles clearly has experience with *pro tempore* moderation, which would be an invaluable resource to the mod team of LH, as (as far as I could tell) none of the accepted nominations for moderator on this page have prior experience as diamond moderators.

Gilles has also expressed in interest in helping out with the crystallization of LH's scope, as his [MLH profile](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1214/gilles) attests; he brought [a new view](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1334/59) of [scope](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2351/59) to the table, which I think will be very helpful in moving forward on that front.

---

Gilles declined the nomination, in a [comment](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/moderator-pro-tempore/2352?noredirect=1#comment2999_2352) on this answer:

> Thank you for the show of confidence, but I decline. (My participation
> here is too low to be considered anyway.) My interest in this site is
> too low: I am absolutely not a lifehack enthusiast, I've never cared
> how conventional a solution is. My sole concern with this site is that
> I don't want to see it become a repository of inferior answers where
> participating enthusiasts favor “unconventional” answers yet the vast
> majority of readers are looking for the best answer and don't care
> about conventionality. I'm willing to share my experience of SE beta
> sites, but not to the extent of being a mod. –  Gilles

Comment: Thank you for the show of confidence, but I decline. (My participation here is too low to be considered anyway.) My interest in this site is too low: I am absolutely not a lifehack enthusiast, I've never cared how conventional a solution is. My sole concern with this site is that I don't want to see it become a repository of inferior answers where participating enthusiasts favor “unconventional” answers yet the vast majority of readers are looking for the best answer and don't care about conventionality. I'm willing to share my experience of SE beta sites, but not to the extent of being a mod.

Comment: All right then, @Gilles. I think you would have been a good moderator here, even so, as I don't think that "expertise" is required to participate meaningfully on this particular  site (both as a moderator, as well as a poster), but I respect your decision. Thank you again for your help with the scope :)

Answer (score 3):

[image] [image] [image]

I have quite a high reputation there on Life Hacks, also I am an active [reviewer](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/21/nicael?tab=activities&sort=reviews) (top [close votes](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/review/close/stats) and [reopen votes](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/stats) reviewer, one of the top [suggested edits](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/stats) reviewers). I don't have a high participation in the local meta, however I [participate on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael) (but I offered 12k rep as [bounties](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/259214/nicael?tab=bounties&sort=offered), so my current rep is low).

I love Disney Movies very much, especially Frozen and Tangled.

Comment: Nicael is the bestest hacker on SE. So maybe he would be a good life-hacker mod? His adoration of [Queen Elsa](https://www.yahoo.com/parenting/town-puts-out-arrest-warrant-for-frozen-queen-111570085682.html) does give me second thoughts.

Comment: ;) @bluet Does "bestest" mean "best of best"?

Answer (score 3):

## [michaelpri](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/20/michaelpri)

#### [Meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/20/michaelpri)

[image: profile for michaelpri on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

In my dealings with him around LH, michaelpri has been both helpful and polite. His current >2K rep speaks to his dedication in adding quality content to this site.
He probably won't remember this, but I contested a point in one of his answers, and he responded politely even while disagreeing with me completely; this incident sticks out in my mind as an example of what kind of user michaelpri is.

He also made the [top page of users](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users) on our Meta site, which is something. (He even has two answers on this page to date; and neither of them are for himself)

I always recalled seeing his user picture on several review queues whenever I went to the review page; looking at the stats pages proves my hunch that he's among the top reviewers on the site *for every type of review*, which is major.

I think michaelpri would make a good moderator on Lifehacks.

---

#### **I gladly accept this nomination**

I am a middle school student, and I'm very interested in computer programming and computer science. Though my age (14) may be a concern to some people, there have been some young and very successful SE moderators (cough cough [Doorknob](http://stackexchange.com/users/1266491/doorknob)). I live near Philadelphia (I go by EST) and I will be going to high school next year. I don't have any background in moderating for SE or other online communities, but I think that it would be cool and fun experience.

Times I will be on LH

- Not on: 5:00 - 12:00 UTC/12:00 a.m. - 7:00 a.m. EST(I am sleeping)
- Sporadically on - 13:00 - 21:00 UTC/8:00 a.m. - 4:00 p.m. EST  (At school)
- On the most - 21:00 - 3:00 UTC/4:00 p.m. - 10:00 p.m. EST
- On weekends, I will either be on (almost) the entire day, or not be on at all, it depends what I have going on

Comment: I read over this again and I think I remember the [incident](http://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2507/what-is-the-best-way-to-open-letter-envelopes/2520#comment4093_2520) that you mentioned

Comment: Yup, that's the one :)

Comment: @michaelpri Sorry about that profile name; I constructed that flair by replacing pieces of another flair from another answer, as I'm sure you figured out :)

Comment: No problem. When the flairs were broken I was seeing if I could fix it and  I just saw that so I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

## [Tim](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/180/tim)

#### [Meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/180/tim)

[image: profile for Tim on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

---

I am a 16 year student living in Cambridge, UK and I am normally active from 4:30pm to 10pm UTC Monday through Friday, and most of the day on weekends. I do have exams, so my participation will drop at points, but I also have long holidays (13 weeks / year).

I have been active on both the main site and meta, and have been on each day (13 consecutive days). I have 6000+ on Ask Ubuntu, and am active in the review queues and general moderation. I have a large number of SE accounts for this reason, and I am knowledgeable with how SE works, and proactive about making the network as good as it can be (I have 500+ rep on Meta.SE).

Currently I am studying Computer Science and Maths as well as 8 other GCSEs, and will be starting A levels in a year - Computer Science, Maths and Physics (to A level) and Geography (only to AS).

Comment: Any reasons for DV? ... or is this a popularity contest?

Comment: http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/another-user-downvoted-me-based-on-my-gender

Comment: Just so that link isn't misinterpreted... Publicly shaming other users, and engaging in long winded comment-wars isn't something I want in a moderator.

Comment: @apaul That's fair enough. But how do you suggest I should handled it? I found the comment offensive, and I reported it - I had to link to the original comment, so that has the user's name in it, and I added his name in there... I did not like the public shaming, but I also didn't like the comment...

Comment: @Tim There's a "flag comment" feature that you can find next to the comment in question (mouse-over to the left, it's right under the upvote). Flag the comment and leave it at that. There was no need to put it up on meta.

Comment: @Origin I disagree. I wanted to explain how I felt about it. There were multiple offensive comments and I was not impressed with what happened - there were also (possibly) people down voting for those reasons...

Comment: If the issue was sexism/discrimination a Meta post on the subject without referencing specific users would have resolved the issue. If an example was really necessary a link to the question would have been sufficient, you didn't really need to point to a specific comment or user.

Comment: @apaul Well I still disagree, and stand by what I did, it was that comment that triggered me wanting to post. However, you are welcome to your opinion :)

Comment: calling people out for things is in a small, but noticeable way, denting their dignity - and usually only leads to bad feelings in either (or both) directions.

Answer (score -4):

## [ihavenodirection](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/users/188/iliveunderawesomerock)

### [Meta](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/users/188/iliveunderawesomerock)

[image: profile for iliveunderawesomerock on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites]

**I accept.**

One of the most active beta user and has the most reputation. Also very active on meta and has taken interest in moderation by answering questions and even having a formula in their profile.

Comment: Why so many downvotes?