# Why was this question about cleaning a sticky floor closed as off-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

This question has been closed as off-topic:

[How do I clean my sticky floor after a party night?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/how-do-i-clean-my-sticky-floor-after-a-party-night)

The only reason justification given by the closers was from Zach, who said:

> [Since cleaning it with a mop and floor cleaner doesn't work, it means you'll need a really heavy duty solution which means there likely isn't a lifehack way to do it](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/2481/how-do-i-clean-my-sticky-floor-after-a-party-night#comment4026_2481)

This reasoning doesn't really make sense to me, since we shouldn't be closing questions just because we don't think there will be an easy to think up answer (a lifehack are supposed to be [creative](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1159/165) after all), or that we're unable to come up with one ourselves. The entire point of SE is for other users to think up answers the asker (and in turn, other people with the same problem) can't come up with themselves. Closing questions because 5 high-rep users can't think up a solution themselves also doesn't make too much sense, in my opinion.

So why was this question closed?

Comment: I think I voted close on this one. My reason is that it is a low quality question with common remedies.

Comment: @Jon It doesn't look like you were one of the users who casted a close vote on it. However, low quality isn't a reason to close a question, it's a reason to downvote it. A moderator over at our sister Arqade wrote an excellent [meta post on this concept](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5498/a-close-vote-is-not-a-super-downvote-please-dont-use-it-as-one) which applies to all stack exchange sites.

Comment: Also, I don't agree with your reasoning of "common remedies", especially in this case. The user include an attempted solution in his question, which is the only common remedy I could think of. In fact, the only answer on that question is something I'd consider a Lifehack. So you can't really close this question by saying common remedies will solve this problem if the user was already tried common remedies and they failed. Additionally, common to remedies to who? What's common to one person may not be common to another, and what's common in one part of the world may not be common elsewhere.

Comment: That you don't agree is an indicator if a possible deadly problem with this site. Not that you don't agree with me. The problem is that there is so much to disagree on. Vinegar or Bleach and water, then mop until clean, is very common not a hack at all. Its a cleaning tip. And what the problem is.is that there is no fine line between tips and hacks. Very subjective all of it.

Comment: related post: http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1318/can-someone-point-out-why-the-answers-to-these-questions-are-lifehacks?rq=1

Comment: this one is relevant as well: http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/should-we-be-downvoting-conventional-answers

Comment: I was the first close-voter on that question. I don't remember now why I voted (I should've [left a comment](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/1347/59)), but, looking at the question now, I don't believe it's off-topic in any way. I think I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: @Shokhet Thanks for reversing your close vote. I'm certainly no stranger to casting a close vote, only to look at the question again later and wonder why I decided to case a close vote in the first place. Mistakes are bound to happen on occasion, after all.

Comment: The question has been reopened, but has already gotten another close vote (too broad). Wow.

Comment: Question is not off-topic but its unclear / too broad (lacking details). VTCed it and left a comment.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Good comment. I didn't agree with the unclear / too broad reasoning some were suggesting, but your comment convinced me otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I think the premise of the question was a little thin... I wouldn't have voted to close it as off-topic though.

I think part of the problem is that close-voters are using off-topic as a catch all, when other reasons like "unclear what you're asking" or "too-broad" would be a better fit. This is a problem we really need to get a handle on... especially while we're still working out what is off-topic.

The main problem with the question was a lack of information:

What exactly was spilled on the floor, what floor cleaner was used, how was the floor cleaner applied...

In this case both too broad and/or unclear would have fit.

> Too-broad - There are either too many possible answers, or good
>   answers would be too long for this format. **Please add details to
>   narrow the answer set** or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a
>   few paragraphs.
>
> Unclear what you're asking - **Please clarify your specific problem or add
>   additional details to highlight exactly what you need.** As it's
>   currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See
>   the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Although I'm not sure if I would agree the question is too broad, I certainly understand your reasoning. I think it makes a lot more sense to close the question as Too Broad than Off-Topic.

Comment: In case the close votes were for "unclear," I've edited the question.

Comment: @Shokhet "What exactly was spilled on the floor, what floor cleaner was used, how was the floor cleaner applied..." The question still looks a little thin.

Comment: Most of that stuff is already in the question, I think. However, what type of floor is not, so I left a comment to that effect.

Comment: I've thought a bit more about it, and although I think that  information would be helpful in improving the question, I don't think it's necessary to for the question to be answerable.