# Could we/should we change our site to "Everyday Living"?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, scope

Given the (quite understandable) [confusion over this site's scope](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/am-i-the-only-one-that-thinks-the-scope-is-confusing), as well as due to [convincing arguments by Gilles](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2353/59), and [Jason's](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2355/59) and [Wipqozn's](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2358/59) concerns with regard to low-quality answers by definition, I think we should consider **switching this site's title to "Everyday Living."**
<sup>*Idea taken from [this post](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2353/59) by Gilles*</sup>

I think this is concurrent with the questions left open on this site at this point. The largest benefits in this change, in my opinion, would be that the purpose of this site will be immediately understood by new contributors, and the usefullness this site has toward most of its users, the casual Google readers, [estimated by Gilles](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1269/moderator-pro-tempore#comment2999_2352) to outnumber LH contributors/registered users.

To counter the argument that this makes the site a "catch-all," I don't believe it would. We've already limited the site to physical, everyday problems, and we won't take questions that are about, say, [programming](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), religion ([1](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/), [2](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/), [3](https://islam.stackexchange.com/), etc) or [co-workers](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/). The questions asked here now will only be about *physical problems encountered in everyday life*.
Heck, any of those sites I just linked to have pretty broad scopes; maybe we should shut down SO, for example, because not every user who knows Java will have anything worthwhile to add under the C# tag. What ties together the scope of SO is that it all has to do with *programming* -- I would argue that the same can be said here; this site's scope is physical problems that can be encountered on a day-to-day basis.

I do realize that this change is more than just a symbol -- it will also, of necessity, change the way that the contributors and the (relatively speaking) long-time users think of the site, and the answers posted -- we will no longer [downvote conventional answers](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1137/59), the [definition of on-topic questions](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1124/59) will change (though it will become a lot easier to understand, IMO), and [What is a lifehack?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/what-is-a-lifehack) will become a moot question.

The only downside I could think of, offhand, was that this still leaves the problem of [Who are the experts?](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5/59) unresolved, though this site always had that problem. I think that we'll just have to make do, in the way that [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) does: the guys with the most fake internet points on the site are the experts.

To clarify: hack answers are still cool and very much expected -- this is, after all, what we're here for, right? But at the same time, to make this site useful to the internet (the greater purpose of why we're here), why (borrowing words from Gilles) should our questions implicitly exclude [the best answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdrW7.gif)*? That's just not useful to anyone.

Thoughts, anyone?

---

* <sup>*Image taken from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/266359)*</sup>

Comment: I'm pretty sure this makes the Lifehacks site a site that isn't about lifehacks anymore. Wouldn't it be better to just propose a new site on Area 51 for this idea rather than essentially get rid of Lifehacks and put this in its place?

Comment: To be clear, I don't think this site is working, and I don't think it's going to work. But I don't think the proper solution is to say "Well, here's sort of what it turned into, which really isn't at all what the proposal was... let's just keep going with it."

Comment: @Sterno Counter-argument: whatever is happening on meta, the set of open questions on the site effectively defines the current scope as “everyday living”. We might as well use the existing questions as a basis, rather than start from scratch. If we *don't* do this, we need to get around to closing questions. Lots of questions. Which of course entails settling the debate as to which questions.

Comment: @Gilles My counter to that would be that the people who signed up for this beta were interested in a site about lifehacks, not a site about "everyday living". The low participation in Meta doesn't lead me to believe there's a huge community desire for the site in its current form. In short, let's make sure the interest exists in such a site before we go to the trouble of trying to make it work.

Comment: @Sterno My informal impression is that the participation on Meta Lifehacks is pretty high compared to most sites. Obviously switching the focus away from hacks will disappoint some people, which is why it's best to have a debate here, to gauge the pros and cons and see how disappointed people would be.

Comment: Everyday people don't tape cookie sheets to their feet to go out and get tacos in a blizzard.

Comment: @GnomeSlice See edit to question.

Comment: OK, so if we do decide to change it how will that affect internet searchability and Scope. I do agree that this might help.

Comment: I think the site name is correct and it should stay. Changing site name (which all peoples agreed to), it'll destroy all the hard work putting the proposal into beta and the site it-self.

Answer (score 4):

I see the reasoning behind this question, but I do believe the answer is **not** to change Lifehacks SE into "Everyday Living" SE. As stated in some of the more recent discussion here on meta, I believe the response should rather be to focus on raising traffic and looking at how to get the quality questions we really want, which does require a lifehack.

In other words, get people to ask questions which shows a little effort regarding what they've tried and *why they need a lifehack* as opposed to everyday, ordinary, conventional answers, which can be found elsewhere.

Answer (score -3):

EDIT:

I think it would be good to have an additional site such as "LifeQuestions" or "WhereToAsk?". I was listening to a podcast and thought of a movie idea I'd like to submit to someone. Where can I do that? Having a catch-all place to ask questions would be good, and stated in the description, only questions not fitting elsewhere should be asked. This would focus attention on the entire StackExchange. Lifehacks could link to it in the header as well as other sites here. Another question I have has to do with edit marks often seen in published material. I would like to ask that somewhere.

---

It will take time to build a reputation so people will come here for answers. They will be led here by search engines. As people find answers they will post questions here, too. I think it would be wrong to change without giving the present focus time to play out.

I don't agree with the question at all, that it should be done, but because it is good to question why things are done, I like it.

I'm pasting a comment I placed on the question mentioned above:

I completely disagree that no one knows what a lifehack is. After looking at the site, the questions, and answers, it becomes clear. We want good intelligent questions and answers, which presupposes people have enough sense to see what the site is about.

Comment: A movie idea shouldn't fit *anywhere* on SE, because that's likely to be "primarily opinion based," which doesn't work very well here. Edit marks might fit on [English.SE](http://english.stackexchange.com/), but I can't say for sure. If you ever want to figure out where you might be able to ask a question, you can ask a question on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/), and tag it [site-recommendation]

Answer (score -4):

Do it.